# Django Ckeditor image browser not finding images

Tags: python, django, image, ckeditor, http-status-code-404

So I'm building a simple blog to keep track of my projects. I decided to use CKeditor as the wysiwyg editor. I was able to get all of it to work except for the image portion of it. I'm not able to view the images in the server when I hit "image browse", and whenever I upload an image, it does upload but I can't view it. It pops up as a red 'X'.

Link to screenshots showing what's happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk9YH.jpg

Below is the code I have where I added CKEditor to my *installed apps* my project's *settings.py*

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'projects',
    'ckeditor',
)
```

Later in my project's *settings.py* I have the setup for CKEditor:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.environ.get('MEDIA_ROOT',os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH   = "uploads/"
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_SLUGIFY_FILENAME = False
CKEDITOR_RESTRICT_BY_USER = True
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'removePlugins': 'stylesheetparser',
        'toolbar': 'Full',
        'height': 500,
        'width': 900,
    },
}
```

Here is my *models.py* for my project (looking very simple for now):

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    banner = models.ImageField(upload_to='banners/')
    body = RichTextField(config_name='default')
    version = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    def __str__():
        return self.title
```

I also have this line to add CKEditor url in my project's *urls.py*:

```
url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
```

Any idea as to might be wrong? Everything works except for the images.
Any Help is strongly appreciated

Comment: From your screenshots, it looks like you are using https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor. If so, what version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in DEBUG/runserver mode, did you remember to add

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        '',
        url(
            r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$',
            'django.views.static.serve', {
                'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
            }
        ),
    )

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

to your `urls.py`

Comment: What is `patterns`?  That's an undefined variable, no?  Can someone fix the indentation?  I'm not sure if the final line is supposed to be within the `if` clause or not.

Comment: As you can see, the answer is from 2014. `patterns` was deprecated in Django 1.8. Earlier versions of Django had `from django.conf.urls import patterns, url` as default imports in `urls.py`.

Comment: Gotcha--so can someone update the answer?  I haven't been able to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing ckeditor image backend

```
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I work with user files and images uploads, 9 times out of 10 the problem is due to bad permissions on the "CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH" folder.

The red X probably is a fallback image in case something goes wrong, such as saving the upload to disk.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem since I stored my images on AWS

I solved it by adding this line in `settings.py`:

```
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

Comment: i already have that line but the issue is still there. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    }),

         ]
```