# Django CKEditor Image Uploads not appearing

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

This is a duplicate of [Django Ckeditor image browser not finding images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111370/django-ckeditor-image-browser-not-finding-images), but I believe the answer there is wrong (there is an obvious bug in it with an undefined variable, not to mention the lack of Python indentation).

I'm using Django CKEditor 5.0.3 and Django 1.9.6.  I am able to upload images in my admin, but they appear as a red X within the admin and do not appear on my site.

I'm still struggling a bit with `MEDIA_ROOT` and whatnot, but I think I have it right:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

MEDIA_URL = "image_upload/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "image_upload")

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_SLUGIFY_FILENAME = False
```

My `urls.py`, including my attempt at cleaning up the linked answer:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from mainsite.views import HomepageView, AboutView, ContactView
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name="admin"),
    url(r'^$', HomepageView.as_view(), name="homepage"),
    url(r'^about/', AboutView.as_view(), name="about"),
    url(r'^contact/', ContactView.as_view(), name="contact"),
    url(r'^blog/', include("blog.urls", namespace="blog")),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$',
            'django.views.static.serve', {
                'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
            }
        ),
    ]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: What worked for me....is changing MEDIA_URL = '/media/' to MEDIA_URL = 'media/' . Note the missing forward slash .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'` makes django-ckeditor to upload an image to `/media/uploads/`, like:

*settings.py*:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
```

When using the Django's dev server, static files are served by default but not media files, so you can force the server to consider them, the url configuration below should work.

*urls.py*:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve
from .views import HomeView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),

# serving media files only on debug mode
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT
        }),
    ]
```

The missing function `patterns` from the [old example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111370/django-ckeditor-image-browser-not-finding-images) was an old function I believe used on Django 1.6 or 1.7.

Comment: Its important to put CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH  after MEDIA_URL else your picture won't be shown.

Answer (score 7):

After installing ckeditor, perform the following :

> 1. In *Settings.py*:
>      add '**ckeditor**' and '**ckeditor_uploader**' into *INSTALLED_APPS*.
>      Add **CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH** = '***uploads_directory***/'
>      (Do not join **MEDIA_ROOT** with the **upload_directory**, ckeditor will take the MEDIA_ROOT as its root upload directory)
> 2. In your ***models*** files:
>      **USE** : `from ckeditor_uploader import RichTextUploadingField` and modify your required model field to type ***RichTextUploadingField***
> 3. In ***urls.py***:
>      add `re_path(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls'))` into ***urlpatterns***

Comment: this is the correct method (as of ckeditor 4 with django 3). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Using Django 1.8 with django-ckeditor 5.3.0, I was getting the exact same symptoms as those above (uploading files worked, but the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag was set incorrectly, causing a red "X" in the preview and broken image links upon publication).

In my case, however, I didn't have to change anything in `urls.py`. My problem was that I had:

`CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "ckeditor")`

So my mistake was giving CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH the path where I wanted ckeditor to upload to (logical, no?).

The fix was to change the above line to

`CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "ckeditor"`

In hindsight I can see how this allows django-ckeditor the ability to use the MEDIA_ROOT for uploading and the MEDIA_URL for serving. Still I thought someone should say it: "Don't use the full path when setting `CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH`!"

I hope this saves others some time.

Answer (score 4):

For **Django 4** the steps to enable image or file upload in `django-ckeditor` is:

**1. Install `django-ckeditor`**

```
pip install django-ckeditor
```

**2. Update `settings.py`**

Add file upload path:

```
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
```

Add `ckeditor`,`ckeditor_uploader` in `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...

    # plugins
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader'
]
```

**3. Update `urls.py`**

Add `path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls'))` in `urlpatterns`:

```
urlpatterns = [
                  ...
                  path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**4. Use `RichTextUploadingField` in `models`**

```
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

class ResearchTopic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = RichTextUploadingField()
```

**Tested with:**

```
Django==4.0.4
django-ckeditor==6.4.0
```

**References:**

- [django-ckeditor documentation](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor)

Answer (score 2):

The @Mohammed-tayab's solution worked for me with a little modification:

`from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField`